# Save image on Clipboard, and can paste to textview on other application

Tags: c#, clipboard, sametime

When i use code as below, i can save image to Clipboard.

```
string file = @"C:\Temp\aaa.jpg";
Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromFile(file));
```

But when i try to Paste(ctrl+v) to another application, such as textbox on IBM SameTime, then will fail, and i try to paste on excel/word work area, it can paste successfully.

The weird thing is, when i use Windows Paint draw someting and right click Copy, it can paste to all application successfully.

I would like to know that is textbox not support Bitmap format?

Please advince, thanks.

Comment: [Clipspy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168/ClipSpy) FTW

Comment: your image is a jpg - it would be more likely the textbox doesnt support jpg.

Comment: Seems not, When i copy the image on Microsoft Paint, it can parse to application textview.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a jpeg stream into a bmp wrapper object. Your application is probably not supporting this while office make this work. Try to convert first your image into bmp format which is apparently supported in your textbox.

Comment: Hi. When i change the image to bmp format, it still can't parse to ST textview. But when i copy on Microsoft Paint, it can parse.

Comment: how did you change the format ? can you try to take a screenshot of your image to make sur it's proper bmp ?